# Appium android clear app data

Tags: appium, mobile-automation, android-automation

My scenario is, I'm switching from one app to another in an Android phone.

While switching from one app to the other, I want to clear all data or do a hard reset of the app I'm switching from. Also before the new app starts (using `driver.activateapp`) I want all data to be cleared.

I tried `driver.resetapp` but, it only reets the first app and not the next one which I'm opening.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

- For your scenario, You want to clear app data for second app.
- So you need to write any method where it will clear app data for second app while switching the application

**How to do it?**

- Option 1 : You can achieve it using `adb shell pm clear <your-app-pkg>`
- Option 2 : You can start your appium server with flag `--full-reset` initially and or while switching after creating driver you can execute method `driver.resetApp()`
- Option 2 was clearing app data of first app because you call it right after driver got initialised for app one. Tweak a little and call it after you initialise driver for second app
- Option 3 :
- Why do not you give a try  to reinstall app instead of `activateapp`
- So for your case, You do not explicitly required to clear app data for second app

Answer (score 0):

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.FULL_RESET, true);
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, false);
```

Have you try this in your one of before methods ?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58766977/how-to-reset-application-in-appium